# Logout of Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion

this is a very stupid question but I just cant figure it out.

How do I log out of Ask Ubuntu (this site)

i am logged in and need to get out (I am on a public computer) but I cant!

Answer (score 8):

It's not that stupid of a question. As soon as I stumbled upon your question I had trouble figuring out how to log out myself. You need to click on the arrow next to StackExchange in the upper left corner of the page above the Ask Ubuntu logo. A small menu will open, and you can click "log out" at the top of the menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps. It is comforting to that I am not stupid ;)

Comment: Can anybody tell if this performs a global logout (from all SE communities) or just from the current one (askubuntu for example)?

Comment: @ByteCommander This performs a global logout.